# Multiple MySQL records with same name, different id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

There might be an easy answer to this, but I can't for the life of me get this to work.

I'm using PHP and MySQL and have something like this set up:

```
    $studentname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
        $studentnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['snumber']);
        $course = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseselect']);

        $bike3 = mysql_query("SELECT stoodnumber FROM bikes505 WHERE stoodname='" . $studentname . "'");
        $bikestoods = mysql_fetch_array($bike3);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stoodlistq))
            {
                $stoodentname = $row['stoodname'];
                $stoodentnumber = $row['stoodnumber'];
                //$coursename = $row2['coursename'];
                //$coursecode = $row2['coursecode'];


                if($studentname == $stoodentname && $studentnumber == $stoodentnumber){
                    //$success = 1;
                        //$success = "yupp";
                        //echo "SUCCESS, WE CAN REGISTER YOOOU!";
                        echo "<br>";

                        //echo "INSERT INTO " . $course . "";
                        switch($course){
                            case "Biking Safely":
                                if($studentnumber = $bikestoods[0] or $bikestoods[1]){
                                    echo "Sorry, this student has already registered";
                                } else if($bikecurrent < $bikemax){
                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO bikes505 VALUES ('" . $stoodentname . "','" . $stoodentnumber . "')");
                                    echo "Yay, successfully registered " . $stoodentname . " - " . $stoodentnumber . " for " . $course;
                                    echo "<br>";
                                } else{
                                    echo "Sorry, class is full!";
                                }
                                break;
```

...and so on. The only problem that I'm having is that if I have two students with the same name, the second in the list will echo that the information is not correct.

For example, the MySQL table has 'stoodname' and 'stoodnumber', and if 'Jimmy St.James','1010' and 'Jimmy St.James','1090' are both records in the table it will only let me enroll Jimmy 1010 in the course and not Jimmy 1090.

Am I just way off with how I'm validating? Or am I missing something really obvious? At first I assumed it was just because I was only using the first item in the array `$bikestoods[0]` so I changed it to `$bikestoods[0] or $bikestoods[1]` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check if it's in the array, in any of its positions. PS: Checking by name is usually a real pain. Real unique data like SSN or something else is better

Comment: You're using `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stoodlistq))`, but I don't see `$stoodlistq` as a MySQL-result anywhere. Where is it defined?

Comment: Sorry, @newfurniturey it's defined as `$stoodlistq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stoodinfo")` I have a couple hundred lines of code so I didn't want to copy and paste everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a comment, you have `$stoodlistq` defined as:

```
$stoodlistq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stoodinfo");
```

Later, you use the following block of code:

```
$studentname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
$studentnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['snumber']);
...
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stoodlistq)) {
    ...
    if($studentname == $stoodentname && $studentnumber == $stoodentnumber){
```

The `while()` loop in this code iterates over every record, however, the `if-statement` checks against the POST variables. The POST variables make up a single combination for "one student" - therefore, you'll only ever get a single student that can be enrolled.

To fix the issue, you'll either need to update your form that submits the "student name"/"student number" to accept multiple inputs - *or* update the `if-statement` to only check against the student's name (which could lead to a more undesired situation).

Comment: Thanks man, I switched things around, the first check is now an `in_array()` that checks for the student number and then the name and everything's working fine and dandy

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your query looking for `stoodname` . When you are doing things like this is not good to do this statements by a value that can be repeated. Maybe you want them to login with a username and password, or maybe with an id that you give to them, but unless somebody here has a better idea, i don't think you will be able to do it by the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bikestoods = mysql_fetch_array($bike3);
```

only refers to the first result of `bike3` query and only has 2 cols : [0] and [stoodnumber] no [1]. If you want to collect all ids that are in bike3, you have to curse the result one time.

```
while($stoodnumbers[] = mysql_fetch_array($bike3));
```